# Как при запуске проекта на qt передавать не функции тестирования, а аргументы командной строки?

Tags: c++, qt, командная-строка, command-line-interface, qtest

Среда - visual studio.
В качестве мэйна файл dsp_test.cpp, после сборки я пытаюсь запустить его в командной строке следующим образом:

```
...\dsp_test.exe "some params"
```

и получаю такую ошибку:

```
********* Start testing of DspTest *********
Config: Using QtTest library 5.15.2, Qt 5.15.2 (x86_64-little_endian-llp64 shared (dynamic) debug build; by MSVC 2019), windows 10
Unknown test function: 'some params'. Possible matches:

dsp_test.exe -functions
lists all available test functions.
```

исходный файл dsp_test.cpp:

```
/*инклуйды*/

int argcc;
std::vector<std::string> argvv;
class DspTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void test1() {
       
        std::cout << argcc << '\n';
        for (int i = 0; i < argcc; ++i) std::cout << argvv[i] << " ";
        std::cout << '\n';
        /*код, где обрабатывается argvv*/
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) \
{ \
    //argcc = argc;
    //for (int i = 0; i < argcc; ++i) {
    //    argvv.push_back(argv[i]);
    //}

    TESTLIB_SELFCOVERAGE_START(DspTest) \
    QT_PREPEND_NAMESPACE(QTest::Internal::callInitMain) < DspTest > (); \
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv); \
    app.setAttribute(Qt::AA_Use96Dpi, true); \
    argcc = app.arguments().size();
    for (int i = 0; i < argcc; ++i) {
        argvv[i] = app.arguments().at(i).toStdString();
    }
    DspTest tc; \
    QTEST_SET_MAIN_SOURCE_PATH \
    return QTest::qExec(&tc, argc, argv); \
}
//QTEST_GUILESS_MAIN(DspTest)
#include "dsp_test.moc"
```

Пояснение по поводу последнего блока кода:

макрос QTEST (QTEST_GUILESS_MAIN в моём случае) не предоставляет возможности вытаскивать параметры из командной строки, поэтому я скопировал определение этого макроса и добавил туда присваивание этих параметров глобальным переменным argcc и argvv.

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавьте какой-нибудь "свой" аргумент с каким-то "своим" ключом.
Например, `dsp_test.exe -p=<ваши параметры> -t=<параметры для тестирования>`, затем, при обработке, удалите этот параметр, а оставшиеся (те, которые c `-t`) отправьте дальше в тестировщик.

Для парсинга командной строки, рекомендую воспользоваться классом [QCommandLineParser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html)

Дополнение. Свой ключ вы дописываете когда вводите в командную строку ваш исполняемый файл (dsp_test.exe <Вот тут идут параметры командной строки>). Например, я предлагаю вам вызывать ваш исполняемый файл таким образом dsp_test.exe -p="<Какие выши параметры>" -t="<Наименование функций тестрирования>" (в QtCreator параметры командной строки задаются во вкладке "Проекты"->"Запустить"->"Параметры командной строки").

Небольшой код:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

// Создаем парсер командной строки
QCommandLineParser parser;
// Добавляем ожидаемые параметры командной строки
parser.addOption(QCommandLineOption("p", "", "..."));
parser.addOption(QCommandLineOption("t", "", "..."));

// Парсим переданные аргументы приложения
if (!parser.parse(QCoreApplication::arguments()) ) {
    qDebug() << "[Command Line Parse Error]: " << parser.errorText();
} else {
    // Получаем значение параметра -t и создаем из него QStringList
    QStringList params = parser.value("t").split(" ");

    ...
    // Передаем значение параметра -t в тестрировщик
    return QTest::qExec(&tc, params);
}
```

Я использовал статический метод [QTest::qExec(QObject *testObject, const QStringList &arguments)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtest.html#qExec-1)

Comment: А как этот свой ключ добавить в код?

Comment: Я попробовал использовать данный парсер и прописывать параметры как вы подсказали, но ничего не работает, просто выдает синтаксическую ошибку

Comment: @genius дополнил ответ